# Subnautica Below Zero not responding when playing on PC with Xbox Series controller

Tags: pc, controllers, subnautica-below-zero

Usually I am able to play games on my PC using my Xbox Series controller via Bluetooth.
But with this game, it does not seem to work, except when switching from the keyboard/mouse to the controller, it resets the view; or in menus, focuses on the current item, but then none of the buttons/joysticks.

I tried looking for a setting but could not find any. The weird part is for instance if I have the controller connected but using the keyboard, the interactive buttons in-game shows the `A button` instead of `Left-click`.

The controller works well as I can navigate the "Xbox Gamebar" after pressing the `Xbox button` or `Ctrl-G`.

Any advice or setting that might help?

Comment: I've got a bug a few times where there is more than one thing that tries to use the controller and that kinda freezes all controller input (I think it was the DS4 and Steam automatic converter) so I guess try to see if 2 things are trying to listen to inputs? So step 1 I would try steam big picture, and see if it works with that. If it doesn't go into the settings of big picture mode and try to remove the xbox conversion settings, see if now it works

Comment: Make sure your operating system is updated. Xbox Series X|S controller was released in 2020 and older versions of Windows don't support it perfectly. As a workaround, try using a different connection mode. For example, try using USB if you were connecting through Bluetooth.